# I want to get the value from a TextFormField when i press a RaisedButton in flutter

Tags: flutter

TextFormField has it's own property to perform actions, called "onFieldSubmited".

But i want to get the value from the TextFormField, when i press a RaisedButton or something.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a `TextEditingController`

There is a [cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input) for this in flutter's own website. Wonder how you missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextEditingController` to get the value of a specific TextField.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

```
[...]
TextEditingController controllername = TextEditingController();
[...]
TextField(
controller: controllername, //...Rest of the code 
)
```

Use the controllername.value to get the current value of a Textfield for that particular moment.